# Spark Shuffle Configuration: Disk Spill evaluation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is a snapshot produced at the `last stage` of the following code:

```
df = /*a dataframe with 800+ partitions having 26+ GB of data*/
val partitionedDf = df.repartition(col("myColumn"))
partitionedDf.write.partitionBy("myColumn").parquet("output/path/")
```

In a **rarest of the rare** case, all the data moves to single `partition` and one `task` takes to load of writing entire data.

[image]

My `Spark configuration` is:

```
"spark.master" :"yarn-client",
"spark.yarn.am.memory": "5G",
"spark.executor.memory" : "8G",
"spark.executor.cores" : "1",
"spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead":"2048",
"spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout" : "600",
"spark.rdd.compress" : "false",
"spark.executor.instances" : "6",
"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" : "8",
"spark.hadoop.parquet.enable.summary-metadata" : "false"
```

**Problem**:

Since an `executor` cannot accommodate 26+ G, I was expecting a `shuffle spill` on I/O. In `Summary Metrics` section in `SparkUI`, I have seen in version `1.5.2`, rows for `Shuffle spill (memory)` and `Shuffle spill (disk)`. How do I ensure in version `1.6.0`, what exactly happened?

Comment: You see that two workers are partically sleeping while one takes all the work. I think you should be thinking about how you're distributing your data.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Yes I can see that. But this is something not in my control. So put into better perspective, here I am writing a multi-threaded storage job to consume data from 200+ kafka topics every hour. Now, one of the topic has 50x data influx compared to average influx. I need to accomodate this topic with minimal changes in my config. The answer I am seeking is whether disk-spill happened or not, because 1.6.0 version is not showing those metrics.

Comment: I am also looking for a way to avoid load imbalance. Any ideas? I am OK if there are multiple output files.